# Uploaded photo not appearing in firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, image-uploading

I created profile photo upload function using react.That function is working fine (photo successfully uploaded all browsers not firefox) .I put it some console logs and then checked it in firefox photo successfully uploaded  but not appear .In chrome and other browser we can upload and show that photo

Here my function

```
 handleUpload(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const file = this.fileInput.files[0];
  const re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
  const fExt = re.exec(this.fileInput.files[0].name)[0];

  const md5 = require('md5');
  const newFileName = `${this.state.fname}_${md5(Date.now())}${fExt}`;

  // 
  const id = this.state.id;

  const form_data = new FormData();

  if (typeof (file) !== 'undefined' && id !== null) {
    form_data.append('file', file);
    form_data.append('name', newFileName);


    this.props.actions.uploadPhoto(form_data, id, newFileName).then(() => {
      if (!this.props.home.uploadPhotoPending) {
        if (this.props.home.res.profile_img === `img/profile/${newFileName}`) {
          message.success('Image Uploaded Successfully', 2);
          this.handlePCMCancel();
          this.getImgUrl();
        }
      } else if (this.props.home.uploadPhotoError) {
        message.error('Image Upload failed, try again', 2);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and upload modal is like that

```
          <Modal
        visible={this.state.PCMvisible}
        title="Upload Profile picture"
        onOk={this.handlePCMOk}
        onCancel={this.handlePCMCancel}
        footer={null}
      >
        <form onSubmit={this.handleUpload} style={{ textAlign: 'center', padding: 5 }}>
          <Avatar src={this.state.imagePreviewUrl} style={{ color: '#ffffff', borderStyle: 'solid', borderWidth: 4, height: 120, width: 120, borderRadius: 70, marginTop: 10 }} /><br />
          <Alert message="You can only upload images, cant edit the images after uploading" type="warning" showIcon /><br />
          <label
            htmlFor="imgUpload"
            className="fileContainer"
          > <span> Choose&hellip; </span>
            <input
              type="file"
              accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"
              name="imgUpload"
              id="imgUpload"
              ref={(input) => {
              this.fileInput = input;
            }}
              className="inputfile"
              onChange={this.handleFileChange}
            />
          </label>&nbsp;
          <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">Upload</Button>
        </form>
      </Modal>
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Show us your current code.

Comment: yes i added Henkan